# Updated gems, now getting error: ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade, rails-4-upgrade

Trying to update a project from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.0. After updating some gems, I encountered some errors and deprecations, such as calling #scope with a hash when running 'rails s'. After fixing, 'rails s' works, but when I try to go to localhost to test my webapp, I get this error:

```
    ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
     5:       %th Activities
     6:       %th.w140
     7:   %tbody
     8:     - (list = latest_updates_list(@filter[:latest_updates_options])).each do |item|
     9:       %tr= latest_updates_item_helper(item)
    10:
    11:     - if list.length == 0
  app/helpers/dashboard_helper.rb:33:in `latest_updates_list'
  app/views/dashboard/_index.html.haml:8:in `_app_views_dashboard__index_html_haml__3401685304950220196_70213556660400'
  app/views/dashboard/index.html.haml:6:in `_app_views_dashboard_index_html_haml___725444960778701440_70213519668520'
```

This is the 'latest_updates_list' method:

```
def latest_updates_list(option=nil)
    client_ids = current_user.actual_client_ids

    services = {}
    Service.where(:client_id => client_ids).each{|s| services[s.id] = {:name => s.name, :frequency_name => s.frequency_short_text, :per_hour => s.per_hour?} }

    reports = []
    invoices = []
    tickets = []
    employees = []

    list = []
    case option.to_sym
    when :reports
      reports = Report.for_latest_updates(client_ids) if (user_admin? || user_can_report?)
    when :invoices
      invoices = Invoice.for_latest_updates(client_ids) if (user_admin? || user_can_invoice?)
    when :tickets
      tickets = Ticket.for_latest_updates(client_ids) if (user_admin? || user_can_ticket?)
    when :employees
      employees = Employee.for_latest_updates(current_user.filter_client_id, client_ids) if user_admin?
    else
      reports = Report.for_latest_updates(client_ids) if (user_admin? || user_can_report?)
      invoices = Invoice.for_latest_updates(client_ids) if (user_admin? || user_can_invoice?)
      tickets = Ticket.for_latest_updates(client_ids) if (user_admin? || user_can_ticket?)
      employees = Employee.for_latest_updates(current_user.filter_client_id, client_ids) if user_admin?
    end

    list += reports.collect do |r|
       {
         :date => r.updated_at,
         :entity => 1,
         :status_text => latest_update_report_status_text(r),
         :reports_services_text => latest_updates_reports_services_text(r, r.reports_services),
         :report_id => r.id}
    end unless reports.empty?

    list += invoices.collect do |i|
       {
         :date => i.updated_at,
         :entity => 2,
         :status_text => latest_update_invoice_status_text(i),
         :invoice_reports_services_text => latest_updates_invoice_reports_services_text(services, i.reports),
         :invoice_id => i.id}
    end unless invoices.empty?

    list += tickets.collect do |t|
       {
         :date => latest_update_ticket_date(t),
         :entity => 3,
         :status_text => latest_update_ticket_status_text(t),
         :description => t.description_text,
         :ticket_id => t.id}
    end unless tickets.empty?

    list += employees.collect do |e|
       {
         :date => e.updated_at,
         :entity => 4,
         :description => e.text_for_stream,
         :employee_id => e.employee_id}
    end unless employees.empty?

    sorted_list = list.sort{|a, b| a[:date].to_i <=> b[:date].to_i}
    list = sorted_list.reverse!
    list = list.take(50)
  end
```

This is line 33 in 'latest_updates_list':

```
    Service.where(:client_id => client_ids).each{|s| services[s.id] = {:name => s.name, :frequency_name => s.frequency_short_text, :per_hour => s.per_hour?} }
```

And here's my Gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/rails/sass-rails.git
  revision: 8588b7b31d708a91516ae3bda0f57601a860ec28
  branch: 4-0-stable
  specs:
    sass-rails (4.0.5)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.2)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, < 3.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/syreclabs/ckeditor.git
  revision: f0d175a66876d9b3453fb47a7914789660a36a15
  specs:
    ckeditor (4.0.6)
      mime-types
      orm_adapter

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/bearded-nemesis/heroku-rglpk.git
  revision: 760859ce23c6e9d253324a584da6ee351700c48f
  specs:
    heroku-rglpk (0.2.1)

PATH
  remote: lib/plugins/xeroizer-payroll-merged
  specs:
    xeroizer (2.16.5)
      activesupport
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      i18n
      nokogiri
      oauth (>= 0.4.5)
      tzinfo

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      mail (~> 2.5.3)
    actionpack (4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    activemodel (4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.0)
      activemodel (= 4.0.0)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.4)
    activesupport (4.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    addressable (2.3.6)
    annotate (2.6.3)
      activerecord (>= 2.3.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
    arel (4.0.2)
    authlogic (3.4.1)
      activerecord (>= 3.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.2)
      request_store (~> 1.0.5)
    autoparse (0.3.3)
      addressable (>= 2.3.1)
      extlib (>= 0.9.15)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.0)
    awesome_print (1.2.0)
    aws-eventstream (1.0.2)
    aws-partitions (1.149.0)
    aws-sdk (1.38.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      uuidtools (~> 2.1)
    aws-sdk-core (3.48.3)
      aws-eventstream (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      aws-partitions (~> 1.0)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
      jmespath (~> 1.0)
    aws-sdk-kms (1.16.0)
      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.48.2)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
    aws-sdk-s3 (1.36.0)
      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.48.2)
      aws-sdk-kms (~> 1)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.0)
    aws-sigv4 (1.1.0)
      aws-eventstream (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    bcrypt (3.1.7)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
      bcrypt (>= 3.1.3)
    builder (3.1.4)
    capybara (2.2.1)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    celluloid (0.15.2)
      timers (~> 1.1.0)
    celluloid-io (0.15.0)
      celluloid (>= 0.15.0)
      nio4r (>= 0.5.0)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.4)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    dalli (2.7.0)
    database_cleaner (1.2.0)
    delayed_job (4.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.2)
    delayed_job_active_record (4.0.1)
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 4.2)
      delayed_job (>= 3.0, < 4.1)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    dotenv (0.7.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.3)
    exception_notification (4.0.1)
      actionmailer (>= 3.0.4)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.4)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    extlib (0.9.16)
    factory_girl (4.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.4.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.4.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faraday (0.9.0)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    ffi (1.9.0)
    ffi-compiler (0.1.3)
      ffi (>= 1.0.0)
      rake
    font_assets (0.1.11)
      rack
    foreigner (1.6.1)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
    foreman (0.64.0)
      dotenv (~> 0.7.0)
      thor (>= 0.13.6)
    formatador (0.2.4)
    google-api-client (0.7.1)
      addressable (>= 2.3.2)
      autoparse (>= 0.3.3)
      extlib (>= 0.9.15)
      faraday (>= 0.9.0)
      jwt (>= 0.1.5)
      launchy (>= 2.1.1)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.0)
      retriable (>= 1.4)
      signet (>= 0.5.0)
      uuidtools (>= 2.1.0)
    grocer (0.5.0)
    guard (2.6.0)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (~> 2.7)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-rspec (4.2.8)
      guard (~> 2.1)
      rspec (>= 2.14, < 4.0)
    haml (4.0.5)
      tilt
    haml-rails (0.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
      haml (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 4.1)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.9.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jmespath (1.4.0)
    jquery-rails (3.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (4.2.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.6)
    jwt (0.1.11)
      multi_json (>= 1.5)
    launchy (2.4.2)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    listen (2.7.1)
      celluloid (>= 0.15.2)
      celluloid-io (>= 0.15.0)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
    lumberjack (1.0.5)
    mail (2.5.5)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    memcachier (0.0.2)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_portile (0.5.3)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    newrelic_rpm (3.7.3.204)
    nio4r (1.2.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.1)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    oauth (0.5.3)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paperclip (3.5.4)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.3)
      mime-types
    pg (0.17.1)
    pg_array_parser (0.0.9)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    postgres_ext (2.0.0)
      activerecord (~> 4.0.0)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
      pg_array_parser (~> 0.0.9)
    protected_attributes (1.0.3)
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    pry (0.9.12.6)
      coderay (~> 1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    quiet_assets (1.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    rack (1.5.5)
    rack-cors (0.2.9)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.0)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      activerecord (= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
    rb-inotify (0.9.3)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    request_store (1.0.5)
    retriable (1.4.1)
    rspec (2.14.1)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    rspec-core (2.14.8)
    rspec-expectations (2.14.5)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.14.6)
    rspec-rails (2.14.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    rubyzip (1.1.7)
    sass (3.2.19)
    scrypt (1.2.1)
      ffi-compiler (>= 0.0.2)
      rake
    shortener (0.3.0)
      rails (>= 3.0.7)
    signet (0.5.0)
      addressable (>= 2.2.3)
      faraday (>= 0.9.0.rc5)
      jwt (>= 0.1.5)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.0)
    slop (3.5.0)
    spork (0.9.2)
    sprockets (2.12.5)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    strip_attributes (1.5.1)
      activemodel (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
    thin (1.6.2)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 1.0.0)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.20.3)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    timers (1.1.0)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    trim_blobs (0.0.1)
      activerecord (>= 3.2.0)
    twilio-ruby (3.11.5)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      jwt (>= 0.1.2)
      multi_json (>= 1.3.0)
    tzinfo (0.3.55)
    uglifier (2.5.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    uuidtools (2.1.4)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)
    yui-compressor (0.12.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  annotate
  authlogic
  awesome_print
  aws-sdk
  aws-sdk-s3
  bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.1.2)
  capybara
  ckeditor!
  coffee-rails
  dalli
  database_cleaner
  delayed_job_active_record
  exception_notification
  factory_girl_rails
  ffi (= 1.9.0)
  font_assets
  foreigner
  foreman
  google-api-client
  grocer
  guard-rspec
  haml
  haml-rails
  heroku-rglpk!
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  memcachier
  multipart-post
  newrelic_rpm
  paperclip (~> 3.0)
  pg
  postgres_ext
  protected_attributes
  quiet_assets
  rack-cors
  rails (= 4.0)
  rails_12factor
  rb-fsevent
  rspec
  rspec-core
  rspec-mocks
  rspec-rails
  rubyzip (~> 1.1.0)
  sass-rails!
  scrypt
  shortener
  spork
  strip_attributes
  thin
  trim_blobs
  twilio-ruby
  uglifier
  xeroizer!
  yui-compressor

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.1.10p492

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.3
```

I believe it must be a gem issue as it was working before and I haven't changed anything in these files.

This is a copy of the gems I updated:

```
Using activesupport 4.0.0 (was 3.2.18)
Using builder 3.1.4 (was 3.0.4)

Using rack 1.5.5 (was 1.4.5)

Using actionpack 4.0.0 (was 3.2.18)

Using actionmailer 4.0.0 (was 3.2.18)
Using activemodel 4.0.0 (was 3.2.18)

Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.4

Using arel 4.0.2 (was 3.0.3)
Using activerecord 4.0.0 (was 3.2.18)

Using railties 4.0.0 (was 3.2.18)
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1 (was 3.2.2)

Using postgres_ext 2.0.0 (was 1.0.0)

Using sprockets 2.8.3 (was 2.2.2)
Using sprockets-rails 2.0.1
Using rails 4.0.0 (was 3.2.18)

Using sass 3.2.19 (was 3.3.5)
Using sass-rails 4.0.5 (was 3.2.6)
```

This is what I get when I use binding.pry to print out 'client_ids':

```
=> [76,
 73,
 64,
 51,
 22,
 67,
 75,
 36,
 83,
 32,
 62,
 55,
 18,
 20,
 60,
 69,
 68,
 1,
 9,
 77,
 78,
 33,
 57,
 59,
 41,
 63,
 43,
 53,
 71,
 66,
 38,
 58,
 61,
 80,
 6,
 65,
 70,
 81,
 74,
 82,
 79,
 42,
 56,
 50,
 49,
 47,
 45,
 44,
 48]
```

and if I use pry to call that line:

```
[7] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fecc2fdafc8>>)> Service.where(:client_id => client_ids).each{|s| services[s.id] = {:name => s.name, :frequency_name => s.frequency_short_text, :per_hour => s.per_hour?} }
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
from /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/postgres_ext-2.0.0/lib/postgres_ext/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:6:in `visit_Array'
```

Comment: Can you add the code for the `latest_updates_list` method?

Comment: @Nate, updated with the whole method.

Comment: I would check to see if `client_ids` is what you expect. I imagine it should be an array of integers, but if it’s something weird (maybe an array of hashes?), then maybe the `where` method is doing unexpected things.

Comment: @Nate client_ids is just an array of integers

Comment: Can you break each piece of that one line up into its own line? That’ll help figure out which piece is problematic. Is it the `where`? Something inside the `each`? Perhaps one of the pieces of the hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade your `postgres_ext` gem.

You currently have Arel 4.0.2 instead and PostgresExt 2.0.0 installed.

I see that PostgresExt 2.1.3 says “Fixes Arel 4.0.1 issues”.
https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/postgres_ext/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#213

Your version of PostgresExt is incompatible with the version of Rails you have installed. I came to this epiphany because of the stacktrace you recently added.

```
from /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/postgres_ext-2.0.0/lib/postgres_ext/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:6:in `visit_Array'
```

Notice that the problem is a wrong number of arguments in the PostgresExt gem.

Notice anything interesting about this commit?

https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/postgres_ext/commit/4ac6184d4bbfd763044b28f98344a02cf688cca3

It takes that `visit_Array` method and makes it use two arguments instead of 1. That’s the problem. ActiveRecord is trying to call an Arel method using 2 arguments, but PostgresExt has overridden that method to add some features, and their override only takes 1 argument. That’s why these kind of gems that override core features are a bit dangerous to use. You need good test coverage because when Rails goes changing internal bits of their gem, it can quickly break this PostgresExt gem.

You should also consider migrating away from this gem as it says it’s no longer maintained.

A coworker of mine recently showed me this gem called ActiveRecordExtended (odd name, considering it’s Postgres only, but oh well). I’ve never used it so I can’t vouch for it, but it seems to do what PostgesExt does, but is also maintained.

https://github.com/georgekaraszi/ActiveRecordExtended

Comment: thanks! That solved the problem! Really appreciate the help!

Comment: @user2377414 Awesome! No problem.